# Spring Security OIDC + WebFlux Calls Keycloak Every Time

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, spring-webflux

I have configured spring webflux with Open Id Connect with Keycloak as an IDP.

The problem is that for every call to my application, the oauth2 client does a call to keycloak instead of using the security session.

I have configured my webflux security as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ServerLogoutSuccessHandler handler) {
    http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .securityContextRepository(new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository())
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

I have a security context repository saved in the web session.
I have configured my web session in memory like so:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveSessionRepository reactiveSessionRepository() {
    return new ReactiveMapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
}
```

In my logs I can see that a security context has been found:

```
WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : Found SecurityContext 'SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [alex], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{sub=bdc6b386-623f-4fe4-a013-2c694678797b, email_verified=true, name=Aleksandar KIRILOV, preferred_username=alex, given_name=John, family_name=Doe, email=mymail@mail.com}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]' in WebSession: 'org.springframework.session.web.server.session.SpringSessionWebSessionStore$SpringSessionWebSession@5a17f06f'
```

Please help on how to avoid calling keycloak if the security context is still valid in the websession.

Best Regards !

Comment: You are serving a **client** (Thymeleaf or other server-side rendering framework) and not a **resource-server** (`@RestController` or `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody` or other functions returning JSON payloads) with webflux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a colleague of mine found the solution:

It seems that there is a clock skew protection in spring oauth2 client and I had set my access_token to expire after only one minute.

The clock skew protection was also set to one minute meaning that spring will preemptively go and refresh the token since we are close to expiration time.